# Can't display the value of a y variable in the chisq.test output

Tags: r

**The initial quest**

I wanted to perform a chi-squared test on all columns of a `data.frame` and then to show only the most significant results (`p.value <= 0.05`). The first column will be `x` and all the others columns will be `y`. Here is the code:

```
y <- 2

for(y in y:ncol(data)){
  chisq_result <- chisq.test(x = data[,1], y = data[,y]);
  if(chisq_result$p.value <= 0.05){
    print(chisq_result);
  }
}
```

**The issue**

```
Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  data[, 1] and data[, y]
X-squared = 11.166, df = 2, p-value = 0.003761
```

As you can see, the 2nd line shows `data[, y]` and it should be `data[, 4]` (or another column number). In other words, I am not able to display the value of the `y` variable in the `chisq.test` output.

Why would I want this ? Because I have several columns in the `data.frame` which makes several chi-squared tests and without any reference it is sometimes difficult to know which column is related with that output or another.

**The temporary workaround**

I tried different things with `get()`, `eval()`, `parse()` or `do.call()` but nothing seems to work. For now, I just added `cat("X = ", colnames(data)[x], " Y = ", colnames(data)[y], "\n");` as a conditional task in order to get the name of the variables:

```
y <- 2

for(y in y:ncol(data)){
  chisq_result <- chisq.test(x = data[,1], y = data[,y]);
  if(chisq_result$p.value <= 0.05){
    cat("X = ", colnames(data)[x], " Y = ", colnames(data)[y], "\n");
    print(chisq_result);
  }
}
```

... which gives something more usable (see the 1st line), but not satisfying, because I still get the variable name `y` and not the value `4` (3rd line):

```
X =  colname1  Y =  colname4 

Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  data[, 1] and data[, y]
X-squared = 11.166, df = 2, p-value = 0.003761
```

**THE SOLUTION**

Thanks to Roman Luštrik, I used `sprintf()` in order to edit directly the data.name content. Here is the new code:

```
y <- 2

for(y in y:ncol(data)){
  chisq_result <- chisq.test(x = data[,1], y = data[,y]);
  if(chisq_result$p.value <= 0.05){
    chisq_result$data.name <- sprintf("col %s and col %s", x, y);
    print(chisq_result);
  }
}
```

Which gives:

```
Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  col 5 and col 8
X-squared = 11.166, df = 2, p-value = 0.003761
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with your workaround. Here's another one, by replacing the relevant data in the printed object of `chisq.test`.

```
xy <- data.frame(var1 = sample(50:100, size = 20), 
                 var2 = sample(100, 150, size = 20))

x <- chisq.test(x = xy[, 1], y = xy[, 2])

x$data.name <- "something pretty from 1 and 2"
x

    Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  something pretty from 1 and 2
X-squared = 340, df = 323, p-value = 0.2471
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Yes, the work around is not bad, but the main problem remains. I had a look at the `chisq_result$data.name` output but it still shows me the name of the variables but not the values. I get `data: data[, x] and data[, y]` but I want `data: data[, 1] and data[, 2]`.

Comment: @LostGeographer yes, but you have 1 and `y`, and you can construct a any string. For example, `sprintf("data: comparing variables %s and %s", 1, y)`.

Comment: Thanks for your additional information. At first, I did not understand that I could edit the `data.name` string (actually I thought that it was not possible). As you suggested I used sprintf() and to change the string content.